# some ubuntu apps won't start, fails with error message

Tags: unity, updates, gnome-terminal

whenever i try to open software updater, terminal, or IDLE i get  a message saying "failed to launch 'whatever program' then under that it says " failed to execute child process /usr/bin/'whatever program' (no such file or directory). I do have terminator so i am able to run terminal commands if you need any info please let me know. thanks, also feel free to edit the tags.

Comment: What does `echo $PATH` show? How are you trying to "open" them? Are you using Ubuntu?

Comment: /home/isaac/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/db/bin:/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/jre/bin this what it spits out, i am using Ubuntu 18.04, i go to the "start menu" and just click on them, that how i am trying to open them

Comment: also when ever i try to download some thing via the terminal i get this message at the end:  E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)